# What is Google Analytics Paid Search?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

Actually I am struggling over a Google Analytics view (Acquisition Overview). 
There you have following results:

- Organic Search
- Generic Paid Search
- Branded Paid Search
- Paid Search`

I know that `Organic Search` are visitors that come from search results.
I know that `Generic Paid Search` are visitors that come from non-brand search results and clicked on an ad.
I know that `_Branded Paid Search` are visitors that come from brand search results and clicked on an ad.

But what are is the Paid Search` channel?

Comment: Beats me! I wish I knew. Sorry. I hope you get an answer. Cheers!!